# Is there a processing python implementation?

Tags: python, port, processing

There are [javascript](http://processingjs.org/) and [actionscript](http://www.sketchpatch.net/) ports of [Processing](http://processing.org/).
Is there a python port ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [pyprocessing](http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/), which is experimental.

Comment: that's what I was looking for, I'll watch out for road signs :)

Answer (score 3):

And there's the more pythonic: http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Home

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the existing answers: [Field](http://www.openendedgroup.com/field/wiki/OverviewBanners2), via [@yaxu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157251/yaxu)

[image: A fully featured core text editor for code]

[image: Integrate with most things, including Processing libraries]

[image: A sophisticated spline-, image- and OpenGL based drawing systems]

**Update**
As of 15.04.2014 (version 2.1.2) [Processing](https://processing.org/download/?processing) includes a Python mode in development.

Answer (score 1):

[pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) already comes pretty close to covering most of the features of processing, and is very pythonic